# How to get the options declared in SourceModule

Tags: pycuda

I want to know if it is possible to get the options declared in parameters of SourceModule.

How can i do it ?

```
mod = SourceModule(src_device,
                nvcc='/opt/cuda65/bin/nvcc',
                options=['-DRANDPHILOX4x32_7','-DPROGRESSION'])
```

Does it exist a method which do it, something like `mod.get_options()`

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

No, as you can see [here](https://github.com/inducer/pycuda/blob/dc9f058045188c0a722d3d2b28c37e648e648493/pycuda/compiler.py#L252), compile options passed to the source module are not retained in the `SourceModule` object. Instead, they pass straight through to the compile system and there is no way to retrieve them after the compilation has been completed.